# How to get result of below sql query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My table like this:

```
id name 
1  jid1
1  jid2
2  jid1
2  jid3
```

How to get matched id values, in above table `jid1,jid2` have same `id` and `jid1,jid3` have another same id value.

How to get those matched records? I need  how to write query for that?

Expected OUTPUT:

```
id name
1 jid1,jid2
2 jid1,jid3
```

Comment: in MySQL it would be `GROUP_CONCAT`, not sure for MS SQL

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`FOR XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to do so, like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.Id,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.name
    FROM Tablename t2
    WHERE t2.ID   = t1.ID
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS Name
FROM Tablename t1
GROUP BY t1.Id;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac65a/1)

Comment: if i pass jid1,jid2 as parameters in where clause i need to get id value.can you tell me query for that?

Comment: @user1237131 Do you want to get the `id` that have both the names `jid1,jid2` or at least one of them? If one of them then use `WHERE name IN (jid1,jid2)`.

Comment: i need id that have both names common .by using above query getting multiple values?i need common id 1 as output in above query.

Comment: @user1237131 - If you want that the `id` that have ***both*** of the names, try this `SELECT 
  t1.Id,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.name
    FROM Tablename t2
    WHERE t2.ID   = t1.ID
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS Name
FROM Tablename t1
WHERE t1.name IN ('jid1', 'jid2')
GROUP BY t1.Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.name) = 2;` see it [**working here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac65a/3)